# Table of contents doesn't work properly

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a simple LaTeX code that begins with:

```
\documentclass[kursovay]{nanolab}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\input title1.tex

\tableofcontents

\newpage
.....
```

Everything works fine until I add `\tableofcontents`. I tried putting it before and after `\begin{document}` but it didn't help. Here is a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

and I get multiple errors of the following type:

> Package calc Error: `\let ' invalid at this point.
> ...}{section_name}{16}{}.

I tried compiling this in Overleaf and in TeXstudio (latest version) and it still doesn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: your (unknown) class nanolab.cls is doing something wrong.

Comment: Additionally please do remember that we do not have access to files you are including and not providing. So make sure your example is self contained, and if not using a standard class (aka known via CTAN), then provide a like to it as well.